# Creating DataTable and Copy existing DataTable schema?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm using vb.net 2010.
I have a DataSet with a Table and data. 
MyDataSet1 which contains Table1

I want to create another table that is the same as the Table1 but without data, but it should have the columns, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Clone` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx).
Note that it won't work for tables with foreign keys.